# NullReferenceException in rss reader

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, rss, windows-phone

I'm building a news reader for Windows Phone, and I've successfully managed that. However I want to get the top news article. I'm trying this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace App_Name
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set the data context of the listbox control to the sample data
        DataContext = App.ViewModel;
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);

        // Download XML
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("https://www.vg.no/rss/create.php?categories=125,10,12&keywords=&limit=10"));
    }

    private void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var RSSdata = from rss in XElement.Parse(e.Result).Descendants("item")
                      select new RSSItem
                          {
                              Title = rss.Element("title").Value,
                              PubDate = rss.Element("pubDate").Value,
                              Description = rss.Element("description").Value
                          };
        newsListBox.ItemsSource = RSSdata;
        var topItem = newsListBox.Items[1] as RSSItem; // Get the top article
        toparticleTextBlock.Text = topItem.Title.ToString(); // Put the top article into the toparticleTextBlock
    }

    // Load data for the ViewModel Items
    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
        {
            App.ViewModel.LoadData();
        }
    }
}
}
```

but the line that gets the top item and puts it into the TextBlock throws a 'System.NullReferenceException' and my question is: why?

Regards,
Erik

Comment: Hard to tell.  Did you debug and check to see what is null that you expect is not null?  If I had to guess, it's because your RSS has downloaded before your UI has loaded, but again that's a guess.  If you debug, find this is the case, then you'll have to put off filling the UI until after it has loaded.  You'd use the Dispatcher to enqueue a method to fill the UI at a low enough priority that it runs after Loaded.

Comment: What's `null`? `Items` is very likely zero-based, and I'd use the `RSSData` directly anyway. Is there a `Title` property on the `topItem`?

Comment: There's a Title property yes, I'll check on using RSSData directly. I'll also take a look if the download completes before the UI has loaded

Comment: Could I place the toparticleTextBlock.Text change in a repeating loop inside a try-statement within the page's Load() call?

Comment: Take a look at my solution

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by directly accessing RSSdata and turned it into a List - then I accessed it's Title property like this:

```
            var toparticle = RSSdata.ToList()[1] as RSSItem;
        toparticleTextBlock.Text = toparticle.Title.ToString(); // Put the top article into the toparticleTextBlock
```